# For flight delay should we claim against booking airline or operating airline?

Tags: airlines, delays, compensation

We booked a long-distance return flight with Lufthansa on their website, consisting of six flight segments in total, two of which were operated by Austrian Airlines and delayed by 5.5 hours.

Should we submit a refund claim with Austrian (as they were responsible for the delay) or with Lufthansa (with whom we booked and who issued our tickets)?

Comment: Are you looking for EU261 compensation rather than refund? If so, the responsibility lies with the operating carrier. Do you know the reason for the delay?

Comment: Sorry for mixing up the terminology! Yes, I mean compensation and it looks like our case falls under the EU261 regulation. The 1st flight with Austrian was only delayed by 30 minutes (caused by "service check", so the airline's fault, I suppose), but we missed our connecting flight (also Austrian) as a result and were re-booked on 2 more flights, with 5,5-hour delay at the final destination. I realize that the end responsibility lies with the carrier, but not sure if it's Lufthansa's responsibility to deal with Austrian, while our direct contact should be with Lufthansa (who got our money)?

Comment: It doesn't matter who you bought the ticket from, you claim from the airline operating the flight. Good guide (BA specific, but generally useful) here: http://www.flyertalk.com/forum/british-airways-executive-club/1423973-ba-compensation-thread-your-guide-regulation-261-2004-2013-archive.html

Answer (score 3):

I believe you'll need to submit the claim with Austrian first even if you have booked with Lufthansa. The end responsibility is with Austrian as they have been operating the flight even if your booking was made with Lufthansa.